# How to make a C project file or Multiple open source files in Ubuntu using gedit/gcc im a newbie please guide me

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc

the error output is

> "FunctionMain.c:(.text+0xdd): undefined reference to `Sum'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status "

in my Main.c i have a header file which gonna call the Sum reference thingy but it seems doesn't work any suggestion guys?

Comment: I'd suggest you show your code.

Comment: Just string all the files you need to compile together on the command line, e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -o exename Main.c other.c stillother.c -I/path/to/includes -L/path/to/libdir -lib1 -lib2 -Wl,stuff-to-pass-to-linker` Omit anything you don't need. In your case `gcc -Wall -Wextra -o outname Main.c other.c` should do. (if you omit `-o outname` it will compile to `a.out` by default)

Comment: To clarify: C only specifies the language, there's no notion of a *project*. So you're free to organize it. A traditional way is a `Makefile` for building with `make`, combined with a directory structure -- source files are often placed in a subdir `src`.

Comment: Your other problem is you may have declared/defined `Sum` underneath `main()` in `FunctionMain.c`, Just add a declaration for `Sum` before it is used in your code. In that case `gcc -Wall -Wextra -o myexe FunctionMain.c` should work.

Comment: in main.c 

#include "Mathv1.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>



int main(){
char op;
int a,b,total;

scanf("%c",&op);
if(strchr("+*-/%",op))



printf("\n\n");

switch(op){

case '+':scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
 total=Sum(a,b);
 printf("\nTotal is = %d \n",total);
break;

Comment: in filename.h 

int Sum(int x,int y);

Comment: Nevermind, you swapped the string and the char in `strchr` (that's fine)

Comment: thank you so much sir David C. Rankin for helping me out its working now i just put -wall -wextra thanks a lot to all of you :D

Comment: It's `-Wall -Wextra` (that's capital `W` there `:)` Those options just **enable compiler warnings** which will tell you exactly where any problem is and what it is . Always compile with `-Wall -Wextra` and do not accept code until it compiles cleanly without warnings. Good luck with your coding.

Comment: Noted sir . And thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot : #include "filename.h" in main.c. And i don't see the declaration of Sum(a, b)

Comment: ahm i used include"Mathv1.h" earlier i just used filename.h so that it wont confusing

Comment: Anyway Sum is not declared in your programme, you need to do it somewhere.